# Route conflict on multiple usb modems

Tags: networking, routing

I have a problem configuring the USB modem routes to define their respective gateways in Raspberry Pi 4.

I have multiple identical USB modems where there is no possibility to change the gateway IP, so they all have the same IP range and respective gateway:

```
usb0 > 192.168.100.10 > gateway 192.168.100.1
usb1 > 192.168.100.11 > gateway 192.168.100.1
usb2 > 192.168.100.12 > gateway 192.168.100.1
...
```

I need to make each of them have their own route where they point to their own gateway in isolation, so that I can select each of them when I run `curl --interface usbX`.

Individually, the following route configuration works:

```
ip route del 192.168.100.0/32 dev $INTERFACE table $INTERFACE
ip route del default table $INTERFACE
ip route add 192.168.100.0/32 dev $INTERFACE table $INTERFACE
ip route add default via 192.168.100.1 dev $INTERFACE table $INTERFACE
ip rule del from 192.168.100.10/32 table $INTERFACE
ip rule del to 192.168.100.10/32 table $INTERFACE
ip rule add from 192.168.100.10/32 table $INTERFACE
ip rule add to 192.168.100.10/32 table $INTERFACE
```

However, how do I work with multiple devices knowing that there is this conflict of gateways?
That is, how can the routes of the respective modems point to their respective gateways in isolation without one modem interfering with the other?

When trying to run these commands defining their respective IPs, the following errors are returned:

```
Error: argument "usbusb0" is wrong: "table" value is invalid
Error: argument "usbusb0" is wrong: "table" value is invalid
Error: argument "usbusb0" is wrong: "table" value is invalid
Error: argument "usbusb0" is wrong: "table" value is invalid
Error: argument "usbusb0" is wrong: invalid table ID
Error: argument "usbusb0" is wrong: invalid table ID
Error: argument "usbusb0" is wrong: invalid table ID
Error: argument "usbusb0" is wrong: invalid table ID
Error: argument "usbusb1" is wrong: "table" value is invalid
Error: argument "usbusb1" is wrong: "table" value is invalid
Error: argument "usbusb1" is wrong: "table" value is invalid
Error: argument "usbusb1" is wrong: "table" value is invalid
Error: argument "usbusb1" is wrong: invalid table ID
Error: argument "usbusb1" is wrong: invalid table ID
Error: argument "usbusb1" is wrong: invalid table ID
Error: argument "usbusb1" is wrong: invalid table ID
```

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1773060/edit) the question and add output of `ip add`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this:

> ```
> invalid table ID
> ```

Routing table IDs are numeric – they can be *manually* assigned names through `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`, but an interface name such as "usbusb0" does not automatically become a valid routing table ID.

For your script to work, either you need to fill /etc/iproute2/rt_tables with table ID assignments for all possible interfaces, or you need to change your script to derive a numeric table ID from $INTERFACE. (For example, cut off the 'usbusb' prefix, then add 2 to the remaining number.)